# Can trains use permanent magnets to be propelled?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, magnetic-fields, kinematics

Can a train (e.g. like a maglev train) use a set of permanent magnets (not electromagnets) that somehow can be propelled and maintain at least a constant speed with them?

Is this an example of such system: https://www.designboom.com/technology/new-maglev-sky-train-runs-on-permanent-magnets-southern-china-08-15-2022/

Comment: What will provide the energy needed to overcome aerodynamic drag and keep the train moving?

Answer (score 1):

Permanent magnets might allow you to furnish the levitation force needed to lift the train out of contact with the rails, but because they are *permanent* there is no way to switch them on and off and to reverse their polarity- which you must do if you want to actually *push* the train along the track and not just lift it.

Comment: You could imagine a system where the permanent magnets are rotated in place or pulled close to/away from the tracks mechanically to propel? but this is not whats done in practice for sure